# How to store the time only in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

How to store the time in SQLite?

I have use the time as a `static final` value. I was stuck on inserting and retrieving the time  from and to SQLite.

I referred to some sites in Google:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. According to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

But I am confused.
And I am getting this error.

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "From": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,From INTEGER,To INTEGER); at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatem‌​ent(Native Method)

```
public static final String[] titles = new String[]{"Akilam 360","Ipadikku Idhayam",
        "Palsuvai Thoranam"};

public static  final String[] fromtime = new String[]{"05:00:00","07:00:00","09:00:00"};

public static  final String[] totime = new String[]{"07:00:00","09:00:00","11:00:00"};


public static final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.akilam_360,
        R.drawable.ipadikku_idhayam, R.drawable.palsuvai_thoranam};

ListView listView;
List<Program> rowItems;
int  iImageId;
String sTitle,sFrom,sTo ;
SQLiteDatabase db;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dbcon);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    String time = hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timer.setText(time);


    db =openOrCreateDatabase("MukilProgram", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,From TEXT);");

    rowItems = new ArrayList<Program>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        Program item = new Program(images[i], titles[i],fromtime[i],totime[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }


    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM proname;");

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(listview);
    final ProgramAdapter adapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,rowItems, false);
    listView.setAdapter (adapter);


    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        Program rowItem = (Program) adapter.getItem(i);

            iImageId = rowItem.getImageId();
            sTitle = rowItem.getTitle();
            sFrom = rowItem.getFromtime();
            sTo  = rowItem.getTotime();


            //sQuantity = rowItem.getQuantity();
           db.execSQL("INSERT INTO proname VALUES("+ iImageId + ",'" + sTitle + "','"+sFrom+"','"+sTo+"');");
            Toast.makeText(Databaseconnection.this, "Added to the Table..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Strongly recommended - Use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass. Don't stuff all the SQLite logic into the Activity

Comment: Also, does this code work or error? Because you have only declare three columns in the table, but you've inserted four values.

Comment: code is working fine

Comment: but i have declared three columns becoz im checking for the data type is correct or not

Comment: it shows syntax error (code 1)in this

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any errors

Comment: You can't use the `FROM` reserved keyword for a column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `FROM` is a reserved word in SQLite. Don't use it as a column name.

If you only care about "from 5am to 7am", for example, then store two `INTEGER` fields for "seconds since start of day". Or minutes/hours, depending on the granularity of the data you have.

If you need something more complex, (say, your times overlapped at midnight, and the `from` was one day, but the `to` was the next day), then, obviously, you'll have to store the data somewhat differently.

However you want to implement that is up to you, but start with

```
final String TABLE_NAME = "proname";
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" 
 +  "ImageID INTEGER, " 
 +  "Title TEXT, " 
 +  "FromTime INTEGER, "
 +  "ToTime INTEGER" // I think you missed this field
 +  ");");
```

As for the remainder of the code - I don't really understand loading the adapter, and then loading the database. You could just load the database, and use a `CursorAdapter` against the ListView.

Along with that point, ["have you tried the insert() method instead of execSQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251275/2308683)

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "From": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,From INTEGER,To INTEGER);
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: FROM is a reserved keword

Comment: i had doubt in this line  public static  final String[] fromtime = new String[]{"05:00:00","07:00:00","09:00:00"}; is this correct

Comment: @Udhaya Thought you said the code worked in your comment above :/

Comment: @Udhaya Your declaration of the array is fine. I have no idea what you're asking