# SQLite error inserting constraint field - why?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android programming and using SQLite. I am trying to insert into a database called "menu" which has a table called "items". The attributes of this table are "name" and "price" which are text and real respectively. (I would like to apologize for all the code, but I figure these will be useful). My "MySQLiteHelper" class creates the table as such:

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Creating the items table
    public  static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
    public  static final String ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public  static final String ITEMS_PRICE = "price";



    private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "menu";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;

    // create table comments(
    //   _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    //   comment text not null );
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS = "create table "
            + TABLE_ITEMS + "( " + ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME + " text primary key, "
            + ITEMS_PRICE + " real not null );";

    public MySQLiteHelper( Context context ) {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase database ) {
        //Create the items table
        database.execSQL( TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS );
        //Create the combos table
        //database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_COMBO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {
        Log.w( MySQLiteHelper.class.getName( ), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data" );
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS );
        //db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CREATE_COMBO );
        onCreate( db );
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the database "menu" is created within the data/data/package/databases folder. Although I am not able to connect to SQLite using adb shell so I cannot confirm table schema. Upon clicking the insert button my datasource.createComment(String, Float) gets called:

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //Load up the current values in the adapter into this adapter object
            ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>)getListAdapter();
    //Set comment to null
    Comment comment = null;
    //Check to see which button was pressed
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.insert:
            String[] option = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
            int index = new Random().nextInt(3);
            //When inserting comment you just have to pass value
            comment = datasource.createComment("TEST", (float) 12.30);
            adapter.add(comment); //Adding to listview
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            if(getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                comment = (Comment)getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                adapter.remove(comment);//removing from listview
                datasource.deleteComment(comment); //delete from db.
            }
            break;
    }
    //Updating the adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Through some debugging (print statement) I can confirm that database.insert is returning -1. It is not successfuly inserting. The following error gets printed out in my Logcat

```
12-16 23:42:30.002 11063-11063/com.example.sqlite E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting price=12.3 name=TEST
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
        at com.example.sqlite.CommentsDataSource.createComment(CommentsDataSource.java:47)
        at com.example.sqlite.InsertItems.onClick(InsertItems.java:50)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code for my "CommentsDataSource" is below. Please ignore the methods after createComment(). I am editing my professors code one method at a time.

```
public class CommentsDataSource {

    // Database fields
    //Used toe xecute commands on db.
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    //Opening up the mysqlhelper which is in charge of opening up connection and maintaining
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    //Holds all the values from the database
    private String[] allColumnsItems = { MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME,
            MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_PRICE };

    //Creating the default constructor
    public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
        //Give context to the class that manages the connection
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    //Opening up the connction to the db
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        //Open the db for reading and writing
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //getWritableDatabase is what opens the connection
    }

    //Closing the database
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //Creating and commiting comment
    public Comment createComment(String comment, float price) {
        //Insert into comments values('')
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //Load the column id and value into ContentValues
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME, comment);
        values.put("price", price);
        //Now insert into table
        long insertID = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
        if(insertID == -1) {
            System.out.println("JSDLFJLSJDFL");
        }
        //Create a cursor to keep track of results. When creating cursors they equal database.query
        Cursor cursor =  database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, allColumnsItems, null, null, null, null, null);
        //Move cursor tot he front
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //Return the comment which is added to listview
        return cursorToComment(cursor);
    }

    public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
        // select id, comment from comments;
        long id = comment.getId();
        //Debug purposes
        System.out.println("Comment to be deleted: " + id);
        //Deleting from db
        database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME + "=" + comment, null);
    }

    public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        //Select * from comments
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        //Fetching the results of query into cursor
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, allColumnsItems, null, null, null, null, null);
        //Move to front of cursor
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //Iterate through cursor
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            //Add results to arraylist
            comments.add(comment);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
    }

    public Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        return comment;
    }

}
```

I am struggling to see where my mistake is. My constraints should all be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your code, I can assume that you're trying to have unique item name in a table right? If it's the case, then that error is obvious. In your table `items`, you've `name` as primary key and you're trying to insert `TEST` each time. Which is already exists inside the table.

There're 3 ways to solve this problem.

1. Remove primary key constraint from `name` column. But, you can enter duplicate names after that.
2. Don't hard code values while testing. Generate unique name and insert it. Like below

   ```
   int index = new Random().nextInt(3);
   comment = datasource.createComment("TEST" + index, (float) 12.30);

   // concatenate `index` variable to `TEST` that's it.
   ```
3. Take input from user (GUI) and insert it to the table.

**PS**: The method `nextInt(3)` will return numbers from 0 to 2. When you test your code, you get duplicate names. So, beware while using random number generator. I'd like recommend my last point for this.

Comment: The adding index seemed to have fixed it. I completely overlooked that fact. Thank you! Such a simple fix.

Comment: As suggested in other answers please add `_id` column with primary key and auto increment to your table. It'll be helpful to perform operations like `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` etc. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! I plan to make the comment or the "test" part an input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public void onClick (View v) {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //Load up the current values in the adapter into this adapter object
            ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>)getListAdapter();
    //Set comment to null
    Comment comment = new Comment(); //have to change this from null to new Comment();
    //Check to see which button was pressed
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.insert:
            String[] option = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
            int index = new Random().nextInt(3);
            //When inserting comment you just have to pass value
            comment = datasource.createComment("TEST", (float) 12.30);
            adapter.add(comment); //Adding to listview
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            if(getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                comment = (Comment)getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                adapter.remove(comment);//removing from listview
                datasource.deleteComment(comment); //delete from db.
            }
            break;
    }
    //Updating the adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also your `SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Creating the items table
    public  static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
    public  static final String ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public  static final String ITEMS_PRICE = "price";



    private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "menu";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;

    // create table comments(
    //   _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    //   comment text not null );
     private static final String TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS + "("
            + ITEMS_AUTO_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," //this is just _id
            + ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
            + ITEMS_PRICE + " FLOAT)";

    public MySQLiteHelper( Context context ) {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase database ) {
        //Create the items table
        database.execSQL( TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS );
        //Create the combos table
        //database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_COMBO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {
        Log.w( MySQLiteHelper.class.getName( ), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data" );
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS );
        //db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CREATE_COMBO );
        onCreate( db );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using ContentViews within my createComment method. Essentially all im doing is packing the values and then running the SQliteDatabase command, right?

Comment: please try this. As per reading on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117685/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-fai .. There was a null

Comment: also, please remove your `onUpgrade()` code. if you change the database version, It will drop the database (even if you have data on your tables)

Comment: I unfortunately get the same error. I am not exactly sure how to debug properly on android studio either.

Comment: try to check the logcat and click the blue link

Comment: have you changed your `TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS` like on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to creating table with text primary key which ideally should be auto increment. That is why its returning constrain failed.

```
 private static final String TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS = "create table "
        + TABLE_ITEMS + "( " + ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME + " text primary key, "
        + ITEMS_PRICE + " real not null );";
```

It should be

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(
_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,      -- autoincrementing, for Android
NAME    TEXT,
[...]);
```

You may refer 
[Inserting values to SQLite table in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251093/inserting-values-to-sqlite-table-in-android)

Comment: Ahh yes I did forget the _id, but I am still getting the same error.